# Editting the search results page

Tags: magento2, frontend

Even though we have some similar questions here, there is none that could help me.

How can I edit the entirety of the search results page?

[image: the search results page in question]

I want to be able to change this image for another, change few texts, structures.

And why this isn't one of the pages you can edit through  the admin view? this doesn't make any sense

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see exact path of template in magento application then follow below step:

For Magento 1
1) Go to Magento admin panel->systems->configuration

2) Choose your store view on top left corner in Current Configuration Scope ex:english

3) Go to Advanced tab. Under that click on Developer->Debug. If you want both block and view template path hints, click yes on Template path hints (phtml files) and Add Block Names to Hints.

4) Refresh your front-end

For Magento 2
Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront > Yes

Hope this helps you !!!

Comment: I actually tried this and came up to a dead end,  the block in question  'breadcrumbs.phtml" and it's file does not make a call to a image, i'm running out of options as of right now

Comment: Can you please put screenshot here with hints so I can assist you exact path.

Comment: the path in question for the block would be 
magento/app/design/frontend/Mgs/molly/Magento_Theme/templates/html/breadcrumbs.phtml